# Filter Out NULL Columns from GROUP BY CUBE Results

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, grouping

I am using `GROUP BY CUBE` to output 
the **Total Min.** for each **Incident #** for each year.

```
SELECT
            IncidentNumber AS [Incident #]
          , SUM(Duration) AS [Total Min.]
          , YEAR(EntryDateTime) AS [Year]

     FROM TableX
     WHERE 
    GROUP BY CUBE
    (
        IncidentNumber
          , YEAR(EntryDateTime)
    )
```

But I don't want rows where the **Year** is `NULL` becuase 
they are redundant of the information from the rows 
showing the years.

OUTPUT

[image]

So I set this as a subquery.

```
    SELECT * FROM
    (
            SELECT
                        IncidentNumber AS [Incident #]
                      , SUM(Duration) AS [Total Min.]
                      , YEAR(EntryDateTime) AS [Year]

                 FROM TableX
                 WHERE 
                GROUP BY CUBE
                (
                    IncidentNumber
                      , YEAR(EntryDateTime)
                )
    ) T
    WHERE T.Year IS NOT NULL;
```

Is there an alternative where I can filter out the
`NULL` without making this a subquery?

If I use GROUP BY ROLLUP I still get NULL.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could add

```
HAVING GROUPING(YEAR(EntryDateTime))=0
```

But the most efficient way would be to just not calculate it at all if you don't need it.

you can use `ROLLUP` instead

```
GROUP BY ROLLUP (YEAR(EntryDateTime), IncidentNumber)
```

And if you don't even want the grand total row you can use `GROUPING SETS`

```
GROUP  BY GROUPING SETS ( (IncidentNumber, YEAR(EntryDateTime)), 
                           (YEAR(EntryDateTime)) 
                         )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  But GROUP BY ROLLUP gives me extra row where the year is NULL.

Comment: @Dombey you can still use the HAVING to get rid of that single row. Even better would be to use GROUPING SETS but I'll leave that to you to research

Comment: @Dombey - Example now added